# Unwanted left margin with Simple Scrollbar script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am using the *Simple Scrollbar script* (https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar) to customize the scrollbar of a sidebar.

The problem is that this script pushes the content inside the sidebar 18 pixels to the right. I would like to use the full width of the sidebar to display an image. I have been banging my head on this problem for a few hours now. I think it is something simple but haven't been able to solve this issue.

To illustrate the problem I have created a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgWZdo.

How can I remove the unwanted 18 pixels to the left of the image and thus display the image using the full width of the sidebar?

The `.ss-content` class contains the code that pushes the content to the right:

```
.ss-content {
    right: -18px;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to move the image to the left of the container (red background) in your Codepen example? If so, left: -18px should do the trick.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The problem is if I apply 'left: -18px;' the unwanted margin appears to the right of the image. Removing the 'right: -18px;' is also not an option as it is used by the script to hide the original (uncustomized) scrollbar.